# I'm looking for free 3d game engine for D language

Tags: d, game-engine

On DevMaster.net I found only RealmForge. Is this the only choice? Are C/C++ game engines suitable for D? If yes, what difficulties I need to overcome to work with them?

Comment: ..actually, I'm building one. I'll let you know when it's ready for alpha :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think OGRE has D bindings http://www.ogre3d.org/

I know OpenMW is using Ogre and D http://openmw.sourceforge.net/jaws/

Comment: OpenMW just switched from D to C++. Sad.  I seem like D for all it's strengths as a language just can't gain traction because of technical difficulties.

Answer (score 3):

D supports [calling C functions directly](http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/interfaceToC.html), so you could use a C engine, though you'd have to convert the header to D to allow interfacing.  This can be somewhat automated with the [htod utility](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/htod.html).  If you want an engine written in D, you can look on [dsource](http://www.dsource.org/projects/), though I don't know if any of these are actually usable right now.

Answer (score 2):

[Yage3D](http://www.yage3d.net/)
(Yet Another Game Engine) is an open source, cross-platform, and free 3D game engine. It is currently in the early stages of development but is planned to incorporate many features of leading commercial game engines when finished.